# C# getting more than just last part of name from nameof

Tags: c#

This one is pretty straightforward, I have `nameof(Product.#whatever#)` statements thorough my app to prevent typos, get intellisense and ease refactoring. I need something like `nameof(Product.PricePerUnit.Value)` that would return `"PricePerUnit.Value"` instead of `"Value"`, while keeping all the pros I mentioned.

Comment: Scope depends on the eye of the beholder, `nameof` does not. To get something like that you'll have to cobble it together yourself, a la `$"(nameof(Product.PricePerUnit)}.{nameof(Product.PricePerUnit.Value)}"`.

Comment: [#3100](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/3100) and [#373](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/373) proposal

Comment: take a look at this answer -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27898178/why-does-nameof-return-only-last-name

Comment: Cobbling together it is then...